# HTTP redirect request failed error using WinHttpRequest in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, redirection

I created an excel script to download Historic prices from international stocks in a text file, the script used to work fine till last Monday, now everytime that I call this segment of the code addressing finance.yahoo.com page using some parameters to include the specified stock today's page I receive a redirect error, here some part of the code:

```
Function GetTodayStockYahoo(ByVal simbolo As String, ByVal HojaDatos As 
String, Optional ByVal RenglonInicial = 5, Optional ByVal ColumnaInicial = 
1) As Integer
Dim pagina() As Byte
Dim strPagina As String
Dim WebObject2 As WinHttpRequest

PaginaYahoo = "https://es-us.finanzas.yahoo.com/quote/AMXL.MX"

URL = PaginaYahoo
Set WebObject2 = New WinHttpRequest
WebObject2.Open "get", URL
WebObject2.Send
WebObject2.WaitForResponse
strPagina = WebObject2.ResponseText
```

The error occurs on the WebObject2.send line here a screenshot of the message:

[image: Run-time Error]

I read on some sites that the redirect might be caused by the page requesting cookies, seems like before this was not the case but is now, could someone advice how can I modify the script so I can Get the page on a string as it was being done before?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43838109/how-to-download-data-from-web-using-tr-and-td-tag-names

Comment: Still seems that this is not an easy one, looking forward to some comments yet, 

ThX!